# An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll The directory name is invalid

Tags: c#, sql, .net

I am trying to import a CSV file into a SQL server database. But when I select the file it breaks at `var AllFiles = new DirectoryInfo(CSVpath).GetFiles() ;` with an error message:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll The directory name is invalid.

(note the "The directory name is invalid."
has been translated from the dutch sentence "De mapnaam is ongeldig.")

```
     string server = "LOCALHOST";
    string database = "klantbestand";
    string SQLServerConnectionString = String.Format("Data Source={0};Initial Catalog={1};Integrated Security=true", server, database);


    string CSVpath = txtfilePath.Text; // CSV file Path
    string CSVFileConnectionString = String.Format(CSVpath);

    var AllFiles = new DirectoryInfo(CSVpath).GetFiles() ;
    string File_Name = string.Empty;

    foreach (var file in AllFiles)
    {
        try
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(CSVFileConnectionString))
            {
                con.Open();
                var csvQuery = string.Format("select * from [{0}]", file.Name);
                using (OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(csvQuery, con))
                {
                    da.Fill(dt);
                }
            }

            using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(SQLServerConnectionString))
            {
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(0, "Clientnr");
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(1, "contact");
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(2, "company");
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(3, "address");
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(4, "zipcode");
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(5, "phone");
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(6, "mobile");
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(7, "email");
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(8, "taxnumber");
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(9, "BIC");
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(10, "Bank");
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(11, "SendMethod");
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(12, "Active");
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(13, "Notes");
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(14, "PaymentMethod");
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(15, "Mandate");
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(16, "MandatDate");
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(17, "CollectionType");
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(18, "Country");
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(19, "EmailIntro");
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(20, "PaymentPeriod");
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(21, "Reference");

                bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "GegevensCSV";
                bulkCopy.BatchSize = 0;
                bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt);
                bulkCopy.Close();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Warning!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        }
    }
}

private void btnbrowse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog filedialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    filedialog.Title = "kies csv file";
    filedialog.Filter = "csv Files|*.csv";
    filedialog.InitialDirectory = @"c:\";

    if(filedialog.ShowDialog()== DialogResult.OK)
    {
        txtfilePath.Text = filedialog.FileName;
    }

}
```

Comment: is `CSVpath` a valid directory?

Comment: Simple `CSVpath` represent invalid directory can't you debug and see what's inside

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh CSVpath gets the directory from a browse button that select a file, in the debug it does show the directory to the file

Comment: a file is not a directory.

Comment: how can i make it that it will use the file that i select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty sure the exception is thrown at this line

```
var AllFiles = new DirectoryInfo(CSVpath).GetFiles() ;
```

Its always a good thing to wrap this around a try catch statement. 
But as the exception message says either the paths is incorrect, so it doesnt exist or the syntax is wrong.

Comment: thank you for your help but i would like to know what is wrong with the syntax because i am sure that the path exists.

Comment: If you could post the content of the variable. I might be able to help you.

Comment: i think you mean the `CSVpath` it gets his content from a textbox and that textbox gets filled by a button that selects the file so it would be `C:\Users\s\Desktop\clients TEST.csv`

Comment: You have to escape the backslashes either by using @ at the start of the string or escaping them seperately.

Comment: so i tried to make the `string CSVpath = txtfilePath.Text;` to  `string CSVpath = "@" + txtfilePath.Text;` and i get a different error now now its `The specified path type is not supported.` bare in mind that it was translated from dutch.

Comment: Nvm escaping is only important when u are using string literals. But in your case i think the problem is that you are given the path of a file when u should be giving the path of a directory. so try it without the clients test.csv

Comment: i tried to change `string CSVpath = txtfilePath.Text;` to  `string CSVpath = @"C:\Users\s\Documents";` now the try catch kicked in i think because i got a messagebox with the error  "Classification of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0"

Comment: It seems like the excetpion is coming from somewhere else most likely form your conncection string.